# How to merge two array where one array is dynamic nested values

Tags: php, arrays

I'm having two arrays like this

**$whole_orders**

```
Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 3
                    [food_id] => 1
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [food_id] => 2
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [food_id] => 1
                )

        )

)
```

And **$array**

```
Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [count] => 1
                    [subtotal] => 103.42
                    [tax] => 18.42
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [count] => 2
                    [subtotal] => 303.42
                    [tax] => 38.42
                )

        )

)
```

Here I'm having two arrays such as `$whole_orders & $array` from which I need to merge the **`$array`** values into the **`$whole_orders`**..

And the `$whole_orders` having nested values which are dynamic..

Finally My array should be like this..

```
Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 3
                    [food_id] => 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [count] => 1
                    [subtotal] => 103.42
                    [tax] => 18.42
                )
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [food_id] => 2
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [food_id] => 1
                )
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [count] => 2
                    [subtotal] => 303.42
                    [tax] => 38.42
                )
        )

)
```

It should append nested values of `$whole_orders` array's..

If you think that my title is not correct please change it..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: What logic you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do this it will achieve you desire output ,but when if the count is same for both array

```
foreach($array as $arrayKey => $arrayValue){
    foreach($arrayValue as $key => $value){
        $whole_orders[$arrayKey][] = $value;
    }
}

print_r($whole_orders);
```

Comment: Thank you soooo muchhh... :) You really saved my time....This is exactly what I want... :) :D

Answer (score 2):

Use foreach and iterate your $array and assigned to $whole_orders

```
<?php


 // if $array is always single dimension array   
foreach($array as $array_key=>$array_val)
{
    $whole_orders [$array_key][]=$val[0];    
}

// or if $array is multi dimension array
foreach($array as $array_key=>$array_val)
{
    foreach($array_val as $key=>$val)
    {
        $whole_orders [$array_key][]=$val;
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: It makes an another nested array in `$whole_orders` array

Comment: Hi Naisa purushotham I edited your answer to show the resultant array... And It bring the results like this...

Comment: $whole_orders [$array_key][]=$array_val[0]; I am sure this one will work;

Comment: Thank you so much very simple and easy to achieve :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try below approach..

```
$arr3 = array();
   foreach($arr1 as $key => $value) :
       $arr3[$key] = $value;
       if(isset($arr2[$key])) :
           foreach($arr2[$key] as $k=>$val) :

               $arr3[$key][] = $val;
            endforeach;
        endif;
   endforeach;
   print_r($arr3);
```